# Automatically adding bitmap fonts to font path

Tags: command-line, fonts

I've enabled bitmap fonts on Ubuntu 21.04 and they work fine. I did have this command in my bspwmrc file:

```
xset +fp /usr/local/share/fonts/misc
```

But every time I reloaded the bspwm config file this command was being run again and inserting the same path yet again.
Is there a way to just have this path added once? I tried adding it to `~/.xsession` (since I login with GDM) but it isn't working. I even made this file executable.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.